# How to solve go project issue packages.Load Error on go.mod in VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm often experience this go project issue in vs code.

```
packages.Load error: err: exit status 1: stderr: build flag -mod=vendor only valid when using modules
```

the issue is in go.mod, the effect are the autocomplete or import package couldn't be done automatically.

Perhaps, everyone here run into the same issue, and have a solution.

I Have tried this command, but no effect

```
go mod tidy
go mod vendor
```

I need the permanent solution for this issue.
Thanks!